# Qt / C++ - qDebug << class

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

How do I make qDebug print whether my class exists or not, or information about that class?? Can't believe there's nothing about this on the internet. I need to make sure that my `ink = new InkSpot(this;)` is actually returning something valid.

```
ink = new InkSpot(this);
qDebug << ink;
```

`X:\Development\InkPuppet\inkpuppet.cpp:70: error: C3867: 'QMessageLogger::debug': function call missing argument list; use '&QMessageLogger::debug' to create a pointer to member`

I've tried using QMessageLogger but just get various errors.

My program is crashing because I do something to ink.widget, so I'll post the code for ink

The code calling it is this:

header:
`InkSpot *ink;`

```
void InkPuppet::testButton()
{
    ink = new InkSpot(this);
    qDebug() << ink->widget;
    ui->testButton->setText("working");
}
```

inkspot.h

```
#ifndef INKSPOT_H
#define INKSPOT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QLabel>

namespace Ui {
class InkSpot;
}

class InkSpot : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit InkSpot(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void draw(QPainter *painter);
    QWidget *widget;
    QLabel *label;

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::InkSpot *ui;

};

#endif // INKSPOT_H
```

inkspot.cpp

```
#include "inkspot.h"
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>

InkSpot::InkSpot(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
}
void InkSpot::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QFile *brushInput; //takes raw 8 bit grayscale image, 8 bit values only
    char *brushProto;
    uchar *brushData;

    brushInput = new QFile("x:\\Development\\InkPuppet\\brush.raw"); //open the raw file
    brushInput->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream in;
    in.setDevice(brushInput);
    int size = brushInput->size(); //set size to length of raw file

    brushProto = new char[size];
    in.readRawData(brushProto, size); //read file into prototype
    brushData = new uchar[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        brushData[i] = (uchar)brushProto[i]; //copy char to uchar array
    }

    QImage test(brushData, 128, 128, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    QImage test2(128, 128, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    QVector<QRgb> vectorColors(256); //create color table
    for(int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
    {
        vectorColors[c] = qRgb(c, c, c);
    }

    test.setColorTable(vectorColors);

    for(int iX = 0; iX < 100; ++iX)
    {
        for(int iY = 0; iY < 100; ++iY)
        {
            test2.setPixel(iX, iY, qRgba(255 - (qrand() % 100), 0 + (qrand() % 100), 0 + (qrand() % 100), qAbs((int)test.pixel(iX, iY)-255)));
        }
    }

    //final conversion for stencil and color brush
    QPixmap testPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(test2);
    QPixmap testPixmap2 = QPixmap::fromImage(test);

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawPixmap(150, 50, 100, 100, testPixmap);
    painter.drawPixmap(50, 50, 100, 100, testPixmap2);

    delete[] brushProto;
    delete[] brushData;
    delete brushInput;
}
```

Comment: for starters, you'll want to say `qDebug()` (after `#include`ing `<QDebug>`). That being said, I'm not sure `InkSpot` is a printable type. If it derives from `QObject`, you might be able to interrogate it's `metaobject` ([QMetaObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetaobject.html)). Also see the [QDebug](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdebug.html) reference.

Comment: thanks, that seems to have done the trick, unfortunately it only returns the memory address for the object, not too sure about how to get other information. I'm trying to do this because everytime I do anything to the widget in InkSpot the program crashes. I'll edit with more code.

Comment: I mis-communicated that last part, it happens when I do anything with anything inside of the InkSpot class.

Comment: Actually I know what the problem is now-- it's because I edited out code I thought was still there :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not trivial what you want to do. That qDebug() displays something useful you have to implement the 'operator<<'. The following is a rough example, how this could look like:

```
QDebug inline operator<<(QDebug d, const  InkSpot &f){
        QDebug nsp = d.nospace();
        nsp << f.label->text();
        nsp << "\n";
        return d;
}
```

This prints your InkSpot's label text. Add whatever else information your need. Put above code in your InkSpot.h file, but outside the class definition. If your need to access InkSpots private data, you must make QDebug operator<< a friend of InkSpot.